# MPMoviePlayerController scaling mode is not working in the iPad Landscape mode

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I am using the MPMoviePlayerController to play the live streaming videos, and the code which I am using is

```
[_moviePlayerController.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
[_moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];
_moviePlayerController.fullscreen=YES;
_moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
[_moviePlayerController setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
[self.view addSubview:_moviePlayerController.view];
```

Video is playing in all orientations. But I have added one button on top of the movieplayer which lets you to scale the video.

I know in mediaplayer framework we are having **MPMovieScalingModeNone,MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit,MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill and MPMovieScalingModeFill** types of scaling mode option.
When the button is pressed down, I am setting the scaling mode as  MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill , when it is pressed second time MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit.
This is also works great in the iPhone. But when I am not able to do any scaling operation when I am using the **iPad LANDSCAPE Mode**. Neither I am not able to use Fit or fill scaling mode when the iPad is in the Landscape mode.

Why ? What could be the reason ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the video aspect ratio already fits perfectly onto the display (view) aspect ratio, none of the  fit/fill operations have any effect. That is by design and not a problem.

You should hide or disable that button once such perfect fit is available. To compare the video aspect ratio towards the view's aspect ratio, use the naturalSize property of the player.

```
naturalSize
```

The width and height of the movie frame. (read-only)

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CGSize naturalSize
```

Discussion

> This property reports the clean aperture of the video in square
>   pixels. Thus, the reported dimensions take into account anamorphic
>   content and aperture modes.
>
> It is possible for the natural size of a movie to change during
>   playback. This typically happens when the bit-rate of streaming
>   content changes or when playback toggles between audio-only and a
>   combination of audio and video.

Comment: I guess I have to hide the button. No other options for me . :(. I tried to NSLog what you have told. Like _moviePlayer.naturalsize and while printing the width and height , am getting the values as 640 x 480.

Comment: 1024x768 has an aspect ration of 1.33333 and 640x480 also has an aspect ratio of 1.33333 => perfect fit.

Answer (score 1):

U can provide random scaling like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{

  moviePlayer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.7f, 0.7f);

} completion:^(BOOL finished){
    // if you want to do something once the animation finishes, put it here
}];
```